# virtual keyboard in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, keyboard

[image: two text box : pseudo and password and virtual keyboard]

I am doing a WPF application with a virtual keyboard .As mentionned in the picture, there is two textbox  `pseudo` and `password` and i'd like to enter their values using the virtual keyboard.

The problem is how to know that the cursor is in the first field or in the second one or out. I tried `isfocused` but it didn't give a result.

So how can i do this task?

```
public partial class Authentification : Window
{
    public TextBox numero = new TextBox();
    bool isPseudoFocused = false;
    bool isPasswordFocused = false;
    public Authentification()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        if (Keyboard.FocusedElement == pseudo)
            MessageBox.Show("hhhh");
    }


    private void un_Click(object sender, RoutedEvent e)
    {
        if (isPseudoFocused) pseudo.Text += "1";
        if (isPasswordFocused) password.Text += "1";
    }
    private void pseudo_FocusableChanged(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("pseudo");
        isPseudoFocused = true;
        isPasswordFocused = false;
    }
    private void password_FocusableChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("password");
        isPseudoFocused = false;
        isPasswordFocused = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think somehow you should specify which TextBox you want to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have something like this:

```
bool isPseudoFocused = false;
bool isPasswordFocused = false;

//when Pseudo gets focus the set 
isPseudoFocused = true; 
isPasswordFocused = false;

//when Password gets focus then set
isPseudoFocused = false; 
isPasswordFocused = true;

//when you are typing text then you know where to put your text.
```

UPDATE:

you should put this code into a `TextBox_GotFocus` handler.

```
private void pseudo_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("pseudo"); isPseudoFocused = true; isPasswordFocused = false;
}
private void password_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("password"); isPseudoFocused = false; isPasswordFocused = true;
}
```

Comment: i tried this  `private void pseudo_FocusableChanged(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("pseudo");
            isPseudoFocused = true;
            isPasswordFocused = false;
        }` but nothing is shown

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Keyboard.FocusedElement` for this

Comment: yes, but when you click on of the buttons it shows button is focused.

Comment: yes, because when you click on one of the buttons then that button *will* get the focus. You'll need to keep a reference to the last focused text box, and then use the keyboard button click events to add a single character to one other input fields.

Comment: @paul i did `if(Keyboard.FocusedElement != null) messagebox.show("ok")` but nothing appear