# Virtual Touch Keyboard for WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, touch, virtual-keyboard

Hi I am currently building a WPF application that is supposed to run on a windows 7 OS. Users will interact with the system via a touch screen.

I need a virtual keyboard so users can enter information into the system, but want to prevent them from having access to controls such as ctr+alt+del.

I want something like this: http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/f1/f42/20237d1366083644-annoying-touch-keyboard-problem-microsoft-windows-8-touch-keyboard-mouse.jpg

How do I implement something like this so that the keyboard comes up when a textbox receives focus?

Are there any free / commercial solutions? or do I have to manually implement something like this?

Comment: this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929403/virtual-keyboard-in-wpf-application

Answer (score 0):

This post shows a good way to use Windows p/invoke commands to automatically display the Touch Keyboard when the user clicks on an element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22396330/865666.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because you need to be admin to close the keyboard.